# How to replicate dir step in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, dsl

Below is my pipeline code :

```
dir(my_directory) {
      retry(1) {
             // something
      }
}
```

Is there a possibility to access **dir** step in groovy through the pipeline context ?

I'm thinking of something like this below

```
class StepExecutor {
  // some code
    void dir(String directory, Closure statement) {
        this.steps.dir(directory) { statement }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes: you can import the pipeline steps plugin to access within your shared libraries like you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. It requires you to pass the steps-object of the pipeline though.

```
class StepExecutor {
  
  def steps;
  public StepExecutor(def steps) {
     this.steps = steps
  }
  // some code
    void dir(String directory, Closure statement) {
        this.steps.dir(directory) { statement }
    }
}
```

creating the object from inside of your pipeline:

```
pipeline { ....
   def stepExecutor = new StepExecutor(this);
...}
```